# HiQPdf not displaying Charts on the generated PDF

Tags: c#, asp.net, charts, hiqpdf

I have been using the (free version) HiQPdf libraries to converto html pages to pdf documents.

I am also using in my pages several Chart objecs from the .Net Framework (System.Web.UI.DataVisualization.Charting.Chart) to produce bar graphics dysplaying values changing along time. It works wonders in my local environment when I debug with VS, but when I publish on my IIS or on other servers the charts do not appear at all on the pdf - note: they do appear on the webpages just not on the pdf.

In the Pdfs all the html is displayed correctly, inlcuding css, showing it exactly as seen on the page, except the chart images. I kind of understand that they would not appear as in the html, the image source from the charts results in something like:

```
<img id="MainContent_MyPageControl_ctl00" src="/MyTestWebSite/ChartImg.axd?i=charts_0/chart_0_2.png&amp;g=396d61e14ceb41c08be06fd956cd4dca"
```

Because the real generated png image is not even directly referenced as usual. But the fact is they do appear on the generated pdf when running local from VS, which produces a similar html anyway as the above.
Only difference I see is that when I run local the Image Chart Handler key is defined in the webconfig as:

```
add key="ChartImageHandler" value="storage=file;timeout=20;dir=c:\TempImageFiles\;"
```

but when publishing on a server I have changed it to:

```
add key="ChartImageHandler" value="storage=file;timeout=20;Url=~/MyfolderTempcharts/;deleteAfterServicing=false;"
```

So why dont the charts appear too on my generated pdf, or why they do appear if Im running from VS?

Anyone ever had this problem?

Answer (score 0):

So I have figured out a way to deal with my problem, and I am sharing here if anyone is also in need. The deal is that the Chart objects use http handlers to render the chart generated images (you can read more about it in detail from these guys: https://web.archive.org/web/20201205231110/https://www.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/081909-1.aspx)

At first I thought I could manipulate the html (that I get before the page render) and replace the image sources with accessible links to send to the HiQPdf - for that I would need to temporarely copy the generated images to a public folder. That would be fine unless in my case I deal with sensitive data that should never be accessed even if only momentarily.
So what I do is I check that the image file does exists (in my configured folder) and extract the byte data from it, convert it to base 64 and replace it in the image source html where the handler is, and voila.

example of Base64 html embeded image:

Notice that this manipulated html is never accessible from the outside and is only worked on on the server side, in order to provide a "normal" html that the HiQPdf can pprocess.